# FileNotFoundException Randomly Thrown

Tags: c#

I am developing a C# tool to read 8 gb of hex data from an unformatted SD card.

It is able to do so, but it randomly throws File Not Found Exception. For instance, it will read a gigabyte or two, then throw it. Other times it will read all 8 gbs a few times in a row, then throw the exception. In other words, it appears to pop up completely randomly.

I have no idea what might be causing it.

EDIT: I have used feedback to tweak a few things. What is pasted below is the updated code.

It still randomly throws the filenotfoundexception, but it now ALWAYS throws an argument exception when it tries to read mb 432 of gig 8 (if it gets that far without randomly throwing filenotfound).

The error complains that the filehandle does not support synchronous operations.

```
class Program
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern SafeFileHandle CreateFile(string lpFileName, uint dwDesiredAccess,
      uint dwShareMode, IntPtr lpSecurityAttributes, uint dwCreationDisposition,
      uint dwFlagsAndAttributes, IntPtr hTemplateFile);

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string testOutputDirectory = @"C:\\Users\\aiovanna\\Desktop\\out1.txt"; //Specifies where to write the results of the read.
        try
        {
            SafeFileHandle fileHandle = CreateFile("\\\\.\\E:", 0x80000000, 0, IntPtr.Zero, 3, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            FileStream readStream = new FileStream(fileHandle, FileAccess.Read); //The stream to be read. Is converted to binary.
            BufferedStream bufStream = new BufferedStream(readStream, 1048576);
            FileStream writeStream = File.OpenWrite(testOutputDirectory); //Writing stream opened at the specified directory of output.
            //BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(readStream); //Changes the read stream to binary. Has more powerful methods.

            long gigsRead; //Loop counter that specifies the number of gigabytes read thus far.
            long megsRead; //Loop counter that specifies the number of megabytes read thus far within the current gigabyte.

            Stopwatch totalStopwatch = new Stopwatch(); //Stopwatch to time the total execution of the card read.
            Stopwatch megStopwatch = new Stopwatch(); //Stopwatch to time the execution of reading the current megabyte.
            Stopwatch gigStopwatch = new Stopwatch(); //Stopwatch to time the executation of reading the current gigabyte. 
            totalStopwatch.Start(); //Start timing the program. 
            int bytesRead; 

            for (gigsRead = 0; gigsRead < 8; gigsRead++) //Gigabyte loop
            {
                gigStopwatch.Start(); //Start timer for current gigabyte. 
                for (megsRead = 0; megsRead < 1024; megsRead++) //Megabyte loop
                {
                    megStopwatch.Start(); //Start timer for current megabyte. 

                    try
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1048576]; //Buffer to be read into from card
                        long test = gigsRead * 1073741824 + megsRead * 1048576;
                        bufStream.Position = test;
                        bytesRead = bufStream.Read(buffer, 0, 1048576); //Read from SD card to buffer
                        if (bytesRead < 1048576)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("Didn't read whole chunk!");
                        }
                        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, 1048576); //Write from buffer to output text file.
                        megStopwatch.Stop(); //Stop timer for current megabyte. 
                        Console.WriteLine("Finished mb {0} of gig {1} in {2}", megsRead + 1, gigsRead + 1, megStopwatch.Elapsed);
                        megStopwatch.Reset(); //Reset for next megabyte. 
                    }

                    catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("The error was: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", ex.Source);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Target Site: {0}", ex.TargetSite);
                        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                        writeStream.Close(); //Close writing stream.
                        //reader.Close(); //Close the binary reader stream.
                        bufStream.Close();
                        fileHandle.Close(); //Close the SD card file.
                        readStream.Close(); //Close the filestream reader.
                        System.Console.WriteLine("You will need to turn off your computer, take out the card, turn the computer back on, put the SD card back in, and re-run the program.");
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate.");
                        System.Console.ReadKey();
                        System.Environment.Exit(1);
                    }

                    catch (System.ArgumentException ex)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("The error was: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Param Name: {0}", ex.ParamName);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", ex.Source);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Target Site: {0}", ex.TargetSite);
                        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                        writeStream.Close(); //Close writing stream.
                        //reader.Close(); //Close the binary reader stream.
                        fileHandle.Close(); //Close the SD card file.
                        readStream.Close(); //Close the filestream reader.
                        System.Console.WriteLine("You will need to turn off your computer, take out the card, turn the computer back on, put the SD card back in, and re-run the program.");
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Press any key to terminate.");
                        System.Console.ReadKey();
                        System.Environment.Exit(1);
                    }
                }
                gigStopwatch.Stop(); //Stop timer for current gigabyte. 
                Console.WriteLine("Finished gig {0} in {1}", gigsRead + 1, gigStopwatch.Elapsed);
                gigStopwatch.Reset(); //Reset for next gigabyte. 
            }
            totalStopwatch.Stop(); //Stop total execution timer.
            Console.WriteLine(totalStopwatch.Elapsed); //Print total execution timer.
            writeStream.Close(); //Close writing stream.
            //reader.Close(); //Close the binary reader stream.
            writeStream.Close(); //Close writing stream.
            fileHandle.Close(); //Close the SD card file.
            readStream.Close(); //Close the filestream reader.
            bufStream.Close();
        }

        catch (System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("The error was: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            System.Console.WriteLine("Isolated Storage Exception");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}", ex.Data);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Help Link: {0}", ex.HelpLink);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception: {0}", ex.InnerException);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", ex.Source);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace {0}", ex.StackTrace);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Target Site: {0}", ex.TargetSite);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        catch (System.ArgumentException ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("The error was: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            System.Console.WriteLine("Argument Exception");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}", ex.Data);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Help Link: {0}", ex.HelpLink);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception: {0}", ex.InnerException);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Param Name: {0}", ex.ParamName);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", ex.Source);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace {0}", ex.StackTrace);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Target Site: {0}", ex.TargetSite);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        catch (System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("The error was: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            System.Console.WriteLine("Directory Not Found Exception");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}", ex.Data);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Help Link: {0}", ex.HelpLink);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception: {0}", ex.InnerException);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", ex.Source);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace {0}", ex.StackTrace);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Target Site: {0}", ex.TargetSite);
            System.Console.ReadKey();
        }

        catch (System.ObjectDisposedException ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("The error was: {0}", Marshal.GetLastWin32Error());
            System.Console.WriteLine("Object Disposed Exception");
            System.Console.WriteLine("Data: {0}", ex.Data);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Help Link: {0}", ex.HelpLink);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Inner Exception: {0}", ex.InnerException);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Message: {0}", ex.Message);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Object Name {0}", ex.ObjectName);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Source: {0}", ex.Source);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Stack Trace {0}", ex.StackTrace);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Target Site: {0}", ex.TargetSite);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Below I re-wrote the error that is shown for filenotfoundexception:

> Message: Unable to find the specified file.
>
> Source: mscorlib
>
> Stack Trace: at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(int32 errorcode, String maybeFullPath)
>
> at System.IO.FileStream.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, int32 offset, int32 count)
>
> at System.IO.FileStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
>
> at System.IO.BinaryReader.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
>
> at RawSDAccessTest.Program.Main(String{} args) in C:\Users\etc... at line 67
>
> Target Site: Void WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find the specified file.
>
> Line 67 is:
>
> reader.Read(buffer, 0, 1048576);

What I find really weird here is that the program is perfectly OK with line 65, which also uses the reader object. Somehow between executing lines 65 and 67, it decides that the file no longer exists. I threw the wait in between to see if that would solve it. It didn't.

Any ideas as to what might be causing it to randomly throw this exception, or how to solve it?

EDIT: Process Monitor Shows the following

8:40:26.1077157 AM  SDCardReadAttempt3.vshost.exe   2432    ReadFile    E:  SUCCESS Offset: 3,228,565,504, Length: 1,048,576, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Priority: Normal

8:40:26.1745974 AM  SDCardReadAttempt3.vshost.exe   2432    ReadFile    E:  NO SUCH DEVICE  Offset: 3,229,614,080, Length: 131,072, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Priority: Normal

So in between the reads, the device ceases to exist. I moved the file creation and deletion to the inner loop, so that it will create the file each time it tries to read from it. The problem persists. Smells like hardware to me.

EDIT 2: Now it's occasionally throwing an asynchronous read exception.

9:16:16.1129926 AM  SDCardReadAttempt3.vshost.exe   3752    ReadFile    E:  INVALID PARAMETER   Offset: 7,969,177,600, Length: 1,048,576, I/O Flags: Non-cached, Priority: Normal

I don't know how .net works deep down. Maybe it's making this into a threaded process, when the file isn't opened to be read by multiple threads. I'll toss the wait back in there to see if that eliminates this error so I can get back to the original one.

Comment: Have you tried giving Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) a shot to see if it can give you any more details?

Comment: Intermittent problems like that typically indicate a hardware problem. If it really requires that you reboot the machine after a failure, then I'd very strongly suspect the hardware. What happens if you try to copy the file using COPY or ROBOCOPY or XCOPY?

Comment: @NicoleDesRosiers Seems like a useful tool. Thanks for the recommendation.

Jim: All of these methods want filepath strings. I can't find a way to make a file for an unformatted drive that returns a string.

Comment: I'll throw my hat into the ring. You mentioned it's an SD card. It may be a rather large one. I know that CompactFlash cards were notoriously slow (esp. 8GB ones). I wouldn't expect that to be a huge problem with SD. BUT, perhaps the Read method is timing out while the card is seeking to the next MB to be read, especially after the Wait call? So while Read is waiting for the card to seek and return data, it hits the time out and assumes the file couldn't be found. Just a thought....

Comment: Reading data from an *unformatted* SD card is an oxymoron.  Of course that will fail.

Comment: @HansPassant Pardon my lack of domain knowledge, but I don't see how this is an oxymoron. It is unformatted in the sense that there is no file system. Is unformatted the wrong word here? Also why is it bound to fail?

Comment: Maybe you mean something else, I don't know.  But it sure is unclear to me what *kind* of data you hope to read from a card that wasn't written to before.

Comment: I agree with @HansPassant. If the card is truly unformatted (they're usually pre-formatted with FAT32 or the newer extended eFAT fs (can't remember it's name off the top of my head)), then Windows won't be able to access it as a drive, e.g. E:, F:, etc. And it would be pointless to try and copy data from it because there would be no data. And I could easily see trying to access, say, E:\ would give you a FileNotFoundException because no such directory `\\` exists on the non-existent E: drive.

Comment: That would make sense, but there is hex data written to the card. I know that I'm correctly accessing this data because I copy it to a text file. The only problem here is that it crashes in random spots, leaving me having read and copied only the data up to that point.

EDIT: What I meant to say is that I copy it to a text file, which I can then read and verify that the correct data is there.

Comment: Have you tried setting the ReadTimeOut property of your FileStream?

Comment: I would like to note, as a side note, that `Stream.Read` can read less than the given `length` of bytes. Therefor you'll write the full MB to the output stream even though (possibly) just one byte has been read to the buffer. The rest of the bytes in the array are just (random) nonsense or zeroed out. Also, have you considered other tools to confirm that this is an software/hardware issue?

Comment: Take a look at this code here http://www.fort-awesome.net/blog/2010/03/25/MBR_VBR_and_Raw_Disk it looks to do what you need at a sufficiently low level though youll need to hack it about a little I expect ;o)

Comment: The only problem with the linked code is that I can only move the file pointer to the first two gbs, as the setfilepointer method takes an int.

Comment: Try changing it to a long.

Comment: You're reading data from an *unformatted* device that may or may not contain a file system, and wondering why you're seeing undefined behavior? Seems like the answer is obvious.

Comment: Make sure that your reader is SDHC compatible. The behavior of the device can be very odd if an SDHC card is placed in an SD only reader.

Answer (score 1):

I've had similar problems reading from scanners.  I ended up having to catch the exception, wait for some time (250 ms worked well for my purposes), then try to reread the same data again.  I defined a threshold (6 worked well for me) at which point I gave up and raised an error to the user.
This seemed to give the hardware enough time to catch-up in most cases.

Also, try reading just the block that is giving you trouble.  If you consistently get an error reading a specific block, then you obviously have a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a long shot, but have you tried the ReadAsync method ? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh137813.aspx